# Can't find the network during installation

Tags: networking, server, dhcp, network-bonding

I'm trying to finish setting up Ubuntu 20.04 server on my HP ZBook  laptop, but I can't set up the network correctly.

I can't find my wired LAN. I read the Ubuntu official guide and it says that installation can be done without the network, but even after the installation, I can't find the LAN.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Reboot from your install medium in "Try Ubuntu" mode, open a terminal and use `sudo journalctl  -b 0` to watch your system discover (or not) the hardware.

Comment: Looks like you trying to install Ubuntu Server onto a laptop, which is unusual. Most would do that in a Virtual Machine instead of onto bare metal.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the laptop on the network?
Router has dhcp?
Is not there any restrictions on the network, for example MAC filtering, black listing?

It should not use bond interface, its should be addressed into ens*

I think installer should discover the network if its allowed to get IP from DHCP.